# Why does this SQL code return the maximum value?

Tags: sql, join, left-join, relational-algebra, database-table

I just found this piece of SQL code that returns the row that contains the oldest person:
Assume that you have a SQL table `persons` with two columns, `name` and `age`:

```
SELECT p1.name, p1.age
FROM persons p1
LEFT JOIN persons p2 ON p1.age < p2.age
WHERE p2.age IS NULL
```

Why does this return the maximum? Although I think I know what the left join does, I don't get this example since it uses the same table twice.

Can someone explain what happens here? I really want to learn this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left join restricts the returned values to only rows where the age in `p2` is larger than the age in `p1`, the `WHERE` clause then says only return rows where `p2.age IS NULL`, there can only be one value in `p1` that does not have a value in `p2` that is higher; the highest value (given that the tables are the same data the highest value cannot have a higher value).

Changing the join to be `p1.age > p2.age` would return the lowest age.

EDIT - alternate solution

I think what may be a more efficient way to get the same result would be:

```
SELECT p1.Name, p1.Age
FROM persons p1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT max(p2.age) As MaxAge FROM persons p2) As q ON (p1.age = q.MaxAge)
```

Or maybe

```
SELECT p1.Name, p1.Age
FROM persons p1
WHERE p1.age = (SELECT max(p2.age) As MaxAge FROM persons p2)
```

Not a SQL master so there may be better ways, from a cursory glance at the execution plans they (the two alternatives above) look like they're doing the same but I'm working with a tiny amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is highly inefficient code. Basically it creates an ad hoc set of records
    SELECT p1.name, p1.age
    FROM persons p1
    LEFT JOIN persons p2 ON p1.age < p2.age

For each and every p1, it will show all the p2 s that are older.

When you add the

```
WHERE p2.age IS NULL
```

It will show the p1, where there is no one that is older.

** Side one on efficiency**

The problem with the is that

```
FROM persons p1
LEFT JOIN persons p2 ON p1.age < p2.age
```

creates an ad hoc set of records that is 1/2 (number of persons)^2

Comment: Are you looking for a formal name like a `cartesian join` ?